# Dataflow/Magmi/Pricing - How to set "use config" for certain fields?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magmi, dataflow

I'm trying to update pricing for 2k+ items in our store.

**The problem:** When done with the import, each product is setting the wrong values for both:

- *"Apply MAP"* - (defaulting to **No**)
- *"Display Actual Price"* - (defaulting to **In Cart**)

http://linenwoods.com/test/pricing.jpg

This causes the prices to not show up on the front end. I want each product to use **Use config** for those fields. I didn't see a header for them (when exporting all products through Dataflow) so I'm unsure of what to do.

How can I set those fields to *use config* when importing with Magmi?

Answer (score 2):

you can add following columns to your CSV file while importing through Magmi/Magento dataflow.

1. For Apply Map

   - msrp_enabled 
     and value for this column for "Use Config" should be set to 2
2. Display Actual Price

   - msrp_display_actual_price_type

and value for this column for "Use config" should be set to 4.

I have checked it's working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I overlooked something simple.

Since all products in our store use **use config** for the two aforementioned fields I can just select all products in the admin area and then chose **Update Attributes** (from which I can then select **use config** for those two fields).

Still .. I wish there was a way to specify this with Magmi/Dataflow and prevent this extra step.